# animation with node appendChild() html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

I'm very very new to web development, and I'm trying to create a webpage that will extend down the page as a button is clicked. I found [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_appendchild), which contains this code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>

<p id="demo">Click the button to append an item to the list</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myFunction()
{
    var node=document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode=document.createTextNode("Water");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}
```

Which will add information. I want to do this so it animates in, not just appears. How would I go about this?

Any help or tutorials are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a pure javascript solution, or would you be willing to use jQuery?

Comment: I'm alright with using jQuery, but as I said I'm so new to it you'd have to help with incorporating it into the code, haha.

Comment: [Append and Slide together jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747683/append-and-slide-together-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to read up a bit on jQuery, but there's a description of pretty much what you want here: [jQuery using append with effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520178/jquery-using-append-with-effects)

The principle is to create a jQuery object first, that represents the element you want to append, making sure that it has a style setting that ensures that it is not immediately visible (e.g. `display: none`).

You then append the element into the page (at which point the browser won't render it due to the style setting), and finally use a jQuery method to have it animate into view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Element.animate()**.
For more info read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate).

example:

```
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = 'text'; 
    otherElenet.appendChild(div);
    div.animate([
        // keyframes
        { opacity: '0' },
        { opacity: '1' }
    ], {
        // timing options
        duration: 1000,
    });
```

> Notice, It is not supported by IE

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [bootstrap collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).

Answer (score 0):

The most usual way is to control the CSS style through javascript, as such (these are just examples):

```
// controlling the opacity of an element
document.getElementById(yourElementId).style.opacity = 0.5;
// controlling the position(top) of an element
document.getElementById(yourElementId).style.top = 10;
```

You want to create a set of javascript for whatever animation you want to do, and put that code into the function which is called on the click.
Example of a fade-in effect may be :

```
function myFunction()
{
var node=document.createElement("LI");
var textnode=document.createTextNode("Water");

// fade-in effect. The opacity starts from zero, and increases through 10steps.
node.style.opacity = 0;
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    node.style.opacity = i/10;
}
node.style.opacity = 1;
// end of fade-in effect

node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}
```

(Haven't thoroughly tested it so it may be shaky)

My example was a fade-in, but just do the same for any type of position change or color change or whatever.

Comment: It actually is better to use libraries like jQuery, but I'm just assuming that you want to use only the simple javascript and nothing else.